How can I call/reach "gettype()" from oracledb connection through objects defined in "django.db"?
I have a small Django application with an Oracle DB as database.
I use "Django 5.0.3" with "oracledb 2.0.1".
In "oracledb" library the object "connection" has a method called "gettype()"

see https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/connection.html#Connection.gettype

How can I call/reach this method through objects defined in "django.db"?
DB configuration in "settings.py"
import oracledb
from pathlib import Path

# Database
d = r"/path/to/oracle/instantclient"
oracledb.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=d)

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
        'NAME': '<db-name>',
        'USER': '<db-user>',
        'PASSWORD': '<db-password>',
    }
}

For example, it doesn't work via the "connection" object:
from django.db import connection

def myfunc():
    with connection.cursor() as c:
        c.execute("select * from v$version")
        rows = c.fetchall()
        print(rows)

    my_db_type = connection.gettype("MY_DB_TYPE")

[('Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production', 'Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 
- Production\nVersion 19.23.0.1.0', 'Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production', 0)]
ERROR:root:global error:
ERROR:root:global Exception type: AttributeError
ERROR:root:global Exception message: 'DatabaseWrapper' object has no attribute 'gettype'


You should be able to get access to the underlying connection object this way:
actual_conn = connection.cursor().connection

The connection object that Django supplies is a wrapper.
